# How to get get Application Id in submitting Flink jobs into Yarn use command line interface?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

my team is building a flink based realtime computation platform. We submit flink job to Yarn. 
We create a Process and run commit command use CLI. In order to get yarn application id, we create a thread and parse process output. Application id is used in other methods.

For example, we submit job by this command:

```
nohup flink run  -m yarn-cluster -d -yqu root.default 
-ynm BDP_RTC_FLINK_10457_MultiOutputTestFrontEnd -yjm 1024 
-yn 2 -ytm 1024 -ys 2
```

The output is shown below:

```
2018-10-10 11:21:04 [info] 2018-10-10 11:21:04,629 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Submitting application master application_1536669298614_67675
2018-10-10 11:21:04 [info] 2018-10-10 11:21:04,654 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl         - Submitted application application_1536669298614_67675
2018-10-10 11:21:04 [info] 2018-10-10 11:21:04,656 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Deploying cluster, current state ACCEPTED
2018-10-10 11:21:12 [info] 2018-10-10 11:21:12,699 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - YARN application has been deployed successfully.
2018-10-10 11:21:12 [info] 2018-10-10 11:21:12,700 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - The Flink YARN client has been started in detached mode.
```

We parse process output and get application id: `application_1536669298614_67675`.

Are there any other elegant solutions to get application id in our situation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get the relation between the yarn application and the flink job.

Firstly, list the yarn application.

```
yarn application -list
```

Then, you get the application list, and you can list flink job on the yarn application.

```
./bin/flink list -m yarn-cluster -yid <Yarn Application Id>
```

By the way, you can use

```
./bin/flink run -d
```

not use

```
nohup
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it, then give feedback. Thanks a lot!